# Non Removable Notification in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

From iOS app, I want to post notification on Notification Center continuously. And also, that notification cant be removable from notification center.

I heard that in Android, Non removable notifications is possible. Is it possible in iOS?

Could you please suggest me on this.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732481/correct-way-to-display-today-view-widget-content/26732773#26732773

Comment: Thanks Kampai  for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All notifications in Notification Center on iOS are removable. Maybe you are seeking for the [`Today`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html) widget on iOS 8. It's always shown in Notification Center, you can design your own interface and keep its content updated.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. It is not possible in before iOS. And also I want show the notification continuously.Please suggest.

Comment: Please refer to the `Today` widget. It is shown continuously in the Notification Center. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.